# Apex Test Failure - System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, unit-test, sobject

I am receiving an apex test error - the error message is:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>   Stack Trace: Class.BillingScheduleTest.TestBillingSchedule2: line 108, column 1

When I view the code in the developer console - line 108 code is the below:

```
Asset objAS = [Select Id,Contract__c,Name  From Asset Where Name= 'TestAsset' Limit 1];
```

The whole code can be found at: https://gist.github.com/JennSchnell/1fe9ab2fc2288ad5077baa15ae61ddfa

Still learning a lot of this stuff, but is the error telling me that I don't have an Asset with the name "TestAsset"?

Answer (score 3):

> is the error telling me that I don't have an Asset with the name "TestAsset"?

Precisely. The "List has no rows for assignment" means that you tried to assign the result of a query that returned no records to a variable.

If you get a "List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject" error it would mean the opposite: you got more than one record in your query, and you are trying to assign it to a single instance in your code. In this case you need to either refine your query to get just one record or change your variable type to a list.

Edit:

So, after reading your code, some things come to my mind:

1. On the first line you have `seeAlldata=true` in your class. This means that when the test is run, it will be able to read the data in your organization. No big deal, actually, but you might not need this, see below.
2. Lines 3 to 81 are basically for setting up some test data (which would make the `seeAllData=true` useless.
3. `TestBillingSchedule1` and `TestBillingSchedule2` are methods that will be using the test data created previously. If they are failing then you need to fix whatever is causing the error (in this case, the Asset is missing from the test data).
4. If the `AssetTriggerHandlerTest` class is also failing, you might want to check it before, since it is testing a trigger. The trigger behaviour will likely affect other tests, like the first one you posted.
5. See the [introduction to test methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods).

Comment: So if it is "List has no rows for assignment" - How do I fix the test class?  I don't really need an asset in the database called TestAsset?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on what your test is testing. You can fix the class by making sure that the asset is created and inserted in the database.

Comment: Got it.  So if it was created in the database (production) and an admin deleted the record, than that could result in this error?

Comment: No, actually I meant that in your test execution you need to make sure the Asset object is created and inserted to the database. Specifically, the record needs to have "TestAsset" as its name. If the object is not created during the test, or is created with a different name, then the query fails.

Comment: Maybe I am doing a poor job of explaining, this is a test class that is failing when trying to deploy a change set from sandbox to production.  New to coding in general and the development end of Salesforce.  Also new to this forum. Is there a way for me to post a file of the full code?  Thank you for assistance.

Comment: @JennS records used in test methods should be created in test methods. Don’t use seealldata=true. Any records created during a test are rolled back. If you have not already visit the test method section of trailhead. Without seeing your test class it’s hard to be specific. Your test is most likely failing because you are relying on existing records rather than creating them in the tests

Comment: @JennS you can edit your question to include your test class code. Don't worry if it is too big. You can also upload it to some external service like pastebin or GitHub's Gist (https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Here is the entire code:  https://gist.github.com/JennSchnell/1fe9ab2fc2288ad5077baa15ae61ddfa

Comment: Hi Jenn, so the code isn't failing at line 85 either? Anyway, from the code you posted, your BillingSchedule class probably deletes the Asset record being created during the test or it is responsible for triggering some code that deletes it. What does this class do on lines 75-80? If there is any CRUD operation (insert/delete/update) being done on those lines, you might find the solution there.

Comment: Actually yes Renato the same class errors out with Method Name:  TestBillingSchedule1    

Error Message                                                                                            System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 1 with id 02i0f00000FEB5WAAX; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, If Status is Purchased, Active must be checked: [Active__c] 
Stack Trace: Class.AssetTriggerHandlerTest.testSyncSub: line 83, column 1

I don't completely understand how the methods work.

Comment: Jenn, I've updated my answer. See above for more details.

Comment: I didn't realize they were all connected, but yes I did have three classes that were failing on deployment and the other one was related to the asset trigger.  which looks to be failing on line 83 "update assets", code located here:  https://gist.github.com/JennSchnell/8162f6c83c44e8077f0e35d3480bfd08  thank you very much for the reference of the test method introduction also.  Hopefully I will start understanding this stuff more and more.

Answer (score 0):

It’s best to create your own test data in test classes with code. That way your tests basically build your supplemental test context, test your functionality, and then the test ends and the system cleans up after you.

To fix your specific problem, make sure to create an asset named “TestAsset” in the test method or in a setup method in the test class.

Google Salesforce testing best practices and start from there to learn more about it

Comment: Rather than telling someone to google for a resource, you should link to it and cite a relevant snippet if one can concisely make your point. The whole point of this site is that people should be able to look here for a comprehensive answer. Also, search results change over time.